# Tabindex attribute not working as expected (ios/osx)

Tags: ios, macos, google-chrome, safari

I'm having a problem, that iOS' and osx' voice over reads the `<hr>` tags of my  website. I tried to not allow the user to tab to it with tabindex="-1" attribute, but seems like it is getting ignored and I can switch to my HR tag, and voice over reads it.

Any ideas?

(tried it on ios - safari & chrome, osx - safari & chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aight, found a solution, aria-hidden="true" for the elements I want to hide from the voice over works.